# How to get AS error log to local document using JS?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript

I have created an application, where I need to get error logs (if any) when web services fail. I'm planning to go ahead using ExternalInterface in Flex and using JavaScript. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log errors though the javascript console (viewable in Firebug, for example) with the following line of code:

```
ExternalInterface.call("console.log","Error: Error message goes here");
```

Comment: Certainly a recommended method, but checking for `console` is needed because otherwise you will raise an error when `console` is not available.

Comment: This is method also fine, but I was thiking to create file (like log.txt) in locally and whether can i write error on that file?

Answer (score 0):

What do you plan to do once you pass data from Flash to JavaScript?  Were you expecting JavaScript to create data in local files?  Is that even possible?

I would recommend looking at Flash Shared Objects to store limited data locally.  They are kind of like the Flash version of browser cookies.  If you're using AIR then just create a local File and dump your relevant data in it.